# MediaRequestProtection: An invalid/missing hash value was encountered with Dianoga

Tags: dianoga

I am working on a project with sitecore 9.2 and JSS. I installed Dianoga 4.0.0 for image optimization in development environment.

Some images are getting optimized properly, but for other images I get below error in logs -

```
23668 16:13:08 ERROR MediaRequestProtection: An invalid/missing hash value was encountered. The expected hash value: 887E26BCD8C75EAB53BDC584A335E9C1. Media URL: /-/jssmedia/projectname/data/media/global/img/site/banners/clip-art/invent-make-change.ashx?h=637&w=1440&hash=F44F69ED2F9DA6026E2C0BE77DA18BD5, Referring URL: http://hostname/en/about
```

Can anybody please suggest resolution for this error? Should I use a different version of Dianoga with Sitecore 9.2?

Comment: The hash value is different. 
I’d recommend to check this link: https://doc.sitecore.com/developers/92/platform-administration-and-architecture/en/protect-media-requests.html and look up how the ‘ HashingUtils.ProtectAssetUrl(mediaUrl)’ works. This should give you some hints.

Comment: Thanks @RomanKlimenko for your comment. I changed the hash value in Sitecore.Media.RequestProtection.config. Still no luck. Same issue is occuring.

Answer (score 0):

Dianoga 4 has a lot of known issues. [This one was fixed in 5.0 RC2.](https://github.com/kamsar/Dianoga/issues/56) To get Dianoga working with JSS you'll need Dianoga 5 RC6+.

If you have `Dianoga.WebP.config` enabled and you're using JSS then you need to also enable the `Dianoga.WebP.CDN.config` (even on local). This config changes how the WebP detects browser support for WebP by changing it to the page request checking for `Accept: image/webp` header instead of the image request. This is because JSS at time of writing doesn't pass this header on image requests.